# Creating a KeyEventArgs field with the desired KeyCode value in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, keycode, user32

I wanna make an opportunity to rebind some buttons. I have *"launchParametrs.txt"* file so the **KeyEventArgs** field must get **KeyCode** from *"Start: (bind button from file)"*. But I can't write
`startBind.KeyCode = Keys.F5`. The problem is **KeyCode** is the read-only propertie.

*"launchParametrs.txt"* - is a file that stores Launch Parametrs. It can store for example this text

```
Times: 100
Start: F5
Stop: F6
```

**startBind** is the **KeyEventArgs** field. If that file stores a line `"Start: F5"` then **startBind.KeyCode** must become equals **Keys.F5**

So how can I create a field with the desired KeyCode value?

Alternative solution is transformate the string "F5" to KeyCode.F5. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid we have no idea how your launchParameters.txt file is used, or what `startBind` is. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to provide more context.

Comment: `var key = new KeyEventArgs((Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "F5"));`